# My sound stop working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, pavucontrol

My sound stopped working few days ago and for what I could see online it seems to be the problem that many people have with Ubuntu 16.04. I don't have any clue of what could have caused that. 
My aplay -l gives me this output.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And since I've tried several solutions found here I discovered that also my pavucontrol doesn't give me the option anymore to select the output resource (which before was anyway unplugged).

Any solution known that I don't see?
Thank you!